# Struts2- How to redirect dynamically from action

Tags: redirect, struts2

i am trying to redirect on some action which is dynamic so what is the best way to redirect dynamic from action to struts.xml dynamically

Example : www.abc.com/employee/24/edit
www.abc.com/employee/25/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<result name="redirect" type="redirect">employee/${employee_id}/edit</result>
```

In the action:

```
 private String employee_id;


//create getter & setter for employee_id

public String execute()
{
 Integer EmployeeId= .... //  do other stuff to get employee id 

 employee_id = EmployeeId;
 //this.employee_id=EmployeeId;
 return "redirect";
}
```

Comment: what if i create namespace ?

Comment: Then simply put <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${employee_id}/edit</result>